# Absolute value of a function in $W^{1,2}_0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $u\in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$. Can we conclude that $|u|\in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$? Here $\Omega$ is an arbitrary area in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This should hold, can you help me proving this? I have issues with the not-necessary bounded domain and Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem.. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any references on Sobolev spaces? This is proved in detail in, for example Lieb and Loss's Analysis, via a $C^1$ chain rule. Well, they prove it for $W^{1,p},$ but the proof seems to go through verbatim for $W^{1,p}_0.$ I think it is a little subtle, at least I came up with a false proof on your last question)

Comment: Actually, no! I tried approximate $|u|$ with test-functions, i.e. let $u_\varepsilon \in C^\infty_0$ be such that $u_\varepsilon \to u$ in $W^{1,2}$. Then we can try to approximate $|u|$ with $F_\varepsilon(u_\varepsilon) =\sqrt{u_\varepsilon^2 + \varepsilon^2} - \varepsilon $. But when I try to show convergence, I get some problems with the limit, since I can't find a suitable upper bound such that I can use Lebesgue's theorem...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the case. Suppose that $\Omega$ is bounded and $p \in [1,\infty[$.

First of all, note that if $u,v \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, then $\max(u,v), \min(u,v) \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. In particular, we conclude that if $u \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, then $u^+:=\max(u,0),u^-:=\max(0,-u) \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

It suffices to note that $|u|=u^+-u^-$ in order to conclude.

Comment: Using that $\max(u,v) \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ in order to prove that $\max(u,0) \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ seems like an overkill.

Comment: It certainly is. I wonder what was on my mind when I wrote the answer...